# Does VS2008 require SQL Sever 2005? Can I use SQL Server 2008 instead?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I've noticed that Visual Studio installs SQL Server 2005 Express.  However, I've installed SQL Server 2008 and plan on it being the primary db I work with.  Is it possible to work with VS2008 without having SQl Server 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio does not depend on any version of SQL Server.  You can use SQL Server 2008 with Visual Studio 2008 if you wish.  I am doing so as I type.

Comment: Indeed, me too. Also, you can deselect SQL Server Express when you install VS (just do an advanced install) - can't tell whether the OP knows this from his question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two are independent.  If you are talking about DB Pro, with the latest version of GDR2, you can target SQL 2005 or SQL 2008 databases.